# how do i pass data with & in jquery ajax request

Tags: jquery

Here is a scenario. when ever i pass following in a ajax request.

```
$article = $('#article').val();
$.ajax({
    url:'url.php',
    type:'post',
    data:'article='+$article,
    success : function(response){
        alert(response)
    });
```

so if $article will contain following:

> what is & and what is or.

the script only sends the data what is. not the whole data.

Comment: Did you mean to type respomse? `alert(respomse)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Send the `data` parameter like this instead:

```
data: { article: $article },
```

jQuery will then serialise it into urlencoded format.

Without that the embedded `&` in your string is being treated as the delimiter between key/value pairs.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it will work or not, but you can try to serialize your data before sending it.